# error: ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to run the following query, but it give me the 
following error message:

> ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement
>   transaction.

the query is:

```
 ALTER DATABASE TSQL2012
 SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

and as shown in the pic: any idea why?

[image]

Comment: It suggests that you've already got an open transaction on that connection.

Comment: You're trying to execute multiple statements, one of which is the ALTER DATABASE statement. As the error message states, that's not allowed. What exactly is the source of confusion here?

Comment: just try adding go; after the alter statement.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - it's got nothing to do with the number of statements in the *batch*, the error is in regard to *transactions*.

Comment: I'm copying this from Microsoft original tsql book. how to fix it??

Comment: @DavidShorthose - same comment really as I've made to Anthony - this has nothing to do with *batches*, which is what `GO` is used to separate. This is about *transactions*. A single transaction can span multiple batches. A single batch can span multiple transactions. The two aren't linked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A multi-statement transaction is one that is either created, explicitly, by a [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188929.aspx) statement, or one that has been created by use of the [Implicit Transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317(v=sql.105).aspx) mode - that is, a statement has executed and, before the next statement executes, the [transaction count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187967.aspx) is still greater than 0.

So this implies that, on the connection on which you're trying to execute your code, the transaction count is already greater than zero.

You should execute either `ROLLBACK` (safest if you don't know what was already done in the transaction) or `COMMIT` (safest for preserving data changes already performed), and then you can execute the `ALTER DATABASE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make things easier for you.

The thing is there is an uncommitted transaction there.
So, the sql server just wants you to commit that first and then run this query.

If you dont want that transaction then just close that query window, it will ask if you wanna save it or no.
 Then open new one and then run the query you want.

Answer (score 2):

In my case similar issue was solved by switching to master db, probably because you can't use a db and alter it at the same time.